# Напишите программу для отображения тех чисел из списка, которые удовлетворяют следующие условия

Tags: python, циклы

1.Число должно делиться на 5

Дано например:

numbers = [12, 15, 35, 164, 123, 89, 468, 149, 155, 523, 67]

ОР: 15, 35, 155

Я застрял уже в самом начале кода.

```
numbers = int([12, 34, 56, 67, 89, 120, 138, 151, 52, 84, 347, 473, 499, 524, 789])

while True:
    if numbers % 5 == 0:
        print(numbers)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Без попытки решения ваш вопрос закроют. Представьте ваш код и спросите, что не получается реализовать. Для этого нажмите [edit] под самим вопросом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numbers = [12, 34, 56, 67, 89, 120, 138, 151, 52, 84, 347, 473, 499, 15, 10]
for i in numbers:
    if i % 5 == 0:
        print(i)
```

Comment: А как это сделать в цикле? Например, если число больше 150, то пропустить его и перейти к следующему числу. А если число больше 500, то остановить цикл

Comment: @KileTa Ну почитайте про конструкции `continue` и `break`. Это же базовые вещи.

Comment: @CrazyElf Разобрался, спасибо